# Why click is not working when the button is overflowing other clickable element?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, click, z-index

Here i have a simple custom layout extendable from ViewGroup (btw i tried to extend other layout, does not help) with children (buttons) that are positioned around of central icon (ImageIcon check) and overflowing size of container 50x50(container has clipChildren false). Why does nor z index, nor translationZ nor elevation helps me to overflow other elements. The problem consists in clicks. When i click on button, click is handled on element that is under him (it can be button of same group or element from other list item in recycler view). On picture you can see:
1 is one of the buttons in custom layout where i am trying to perform click
2 is other element in recycler view that is under button
3 is a central icon responsable for opening/closing arc. When it is closed, all of buttons go to the center. Then if i want to open arc, i have problem with seen z-index, click is handled not on central icon but on button that is in center under the central icon.
4 are recycler view elements based on epoxy controller

```
<com.leadely.android.common.ArcLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            app:radius="70dp"
            app:hasCenteredIcon="true"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            app:skip="0"
            app:rotateBy="-120">

            <com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconButton
                android:id="@+id/toggleArcBtn"
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#232323"
                android:text="{fa-check}"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:onClick="@{(e) -> tasksListViewModel.toggleArc(e)}" />

            <Button
                style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button"
                android:layout_width="30sp"
                android:layout_height="30sp"
                android:background="#555"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:text="1"
                android:onClick="@{(v) -> tasksListViewModel.toast(v)}"/>

            <Button
                style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button"
                android:layout_width="30sp"
                android:layout_height="30sp"
                android:text="2"
                android:background="#555"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:onClick="@{(v) -> tasksListViewModel.toast(v)}" />

            <Button
                style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button"
                android:layout_width="30sp"
                android:layout_height="30sp"
                android:text="3"
                android:background="#555"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:onClick="@{(v) -> tasksListViewModel.toast(v)}" />

        </com.leadely.android.common.ArcLayout>
```

What i have to do?

[See Application image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwJbc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in Clickable view, set Clickable and focusable true.

android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"